# Android can't find image

Tags: android, find, drawable

I got this problem here ... it seems that ringer.png does not exist.. and look at the folders-name.. no "Drawable"-words
Where is the probleme ?

[image: Android]

Comment: have you put image in drawable folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because image is not available in `drawable`, its in `mipmap`. Try with this.

```
android:src="@mipmap/ringer_on"
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy all those images and put them into Drawable because mipmap is for our app icon only.

for more details please refer http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html link

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_login_logo" />
```

Try to use mipmap instead of drawable.